# Excel VBA - if weekday of file created date matches cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder directory on a local server at work:

G:\Allocations

```
1.PDF - Created 16/12/16
```

I am also using the following VBA if statement within excel to display a message if the weekday name of a file's created date matches my value in cell A1.

Cell A1 = Friday

```
If WeekdayName(Weekday(objFile.DateCreated)) = Range("A1").Value Then

MsgBox "Date Match"

Else

Msgbox "No match"

End If
```

For some reason if i try this code at home using my Mac, the code works fine and the date shows as a match.

However, for some reason, when i use this code on my work computer, linked to the server, i have to replace Friday with Saturday in order to get a match.

I am not sure why this is, since the file created date remains the same.
Am i doing something wrong, and if so can someone please show me how to fix this?

Comment: Check the **locale** of both computers. It looks that the week's starting day is different.

Comment: @AxelRichter sorry i pasted the wrong part of my code, please see updated question.

Comment: So what about `Weekday(objFile.DateCreated, vbMonday)` since the [Weekday Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh(v=vs.90).aspx) is able specify the first day of the week. Or whatever needs to be the first day of the week for you. Default is Sunday.

Comment: @AxelRichter yea thought about this and tried it, seemed to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions [Weekday Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh(v=vs.90).aspx) as well as [WeekdayName Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8dc1aee(v=vs.90).aspx) are able to specify the first day of the week. But while `Weekday` defaults to Sunday, `WeekdayName` defaults to first day of week specified in system settings. Thats annoying because it must not match in every cases.

So the best practice will be to set the same property for first day of week for both:

```
WeekdayName(Weekday(objFile.DateCreated, vbMonday), , vbMonday)
```

or

```
WeekdayName(Weekday(objFile.DateCreated, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek), , vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)
```